# Gabriel Phthalamide Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, amides

Can we use acid chloride in place of alkyl chloride in Gabriel Phthalamide Reaction?

Maybe it can be used as process to synthesize amides.

Comment: In practice, there's no reason to; you can just use ammonia.

Comment: @orthocresol I mean theoretically if it's a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO, this is not a viable way to make amides.

Phthamide anion will react with acyl halides, but the problem arises with the second step, the removal of the phthalimido group. The usual conditions [described here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/gabriel-synthesis.shtm) of hydrolysis with hydroxide or reaction with hydrazine will result in removal of the acyl group to reform phthalimide plus the carboxylic acid, in the case of OH- hydrolysis, or the acyl hydrazide if using hydrazine. This is because the acyl group is the more electrophilic site for the nucleophile.